# Snap.svg embed html form

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I need to display HTML form in SVG to edit related data. I use Snap.svg library. As I found I need foreignObject tag to embed HTML form there (html code is got by Ajax request).
How can I create such object and embed it to my SVG?

===== EDITED ======
I managed to create foreignObject but I can not put there html

```
            var test = editor.el('foreignObject', {
                x: '20',
                y: '500',
                width: '150',
                height: '200'
            });
```

Comment: html `form` inside **SVG** tag?

Comment: Yes. I create scheme and I have to edit information from scheme element. Now I inserted ForeignObject but can not write there inner html

Comment: Actually I did not hear adding `HTML` (= embedding) it into `SVG` since `SVG` has its own elements. Do you curious maybe it is possible or not, you are sure that it is possible but looking for the right solution?

Comment: I suppose it is possible and now I am finding right solution. One more variant is insert code with jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (html)
            {
                var wrapper = editor.el('foreignObject', {
                    x: '20',
                    y: '500',
                    width: '150',
                    height: '200',
                    class: 'heatNet'
                });
                $('.heatNet').html(html);
            }
```